# MAMP PRO MySQL "Up but not accepting connections"

Tags: mysql, mamp, mamp-pro

So, i've been having this problem with MAMP Pro for over 2 weeks now, it tells me

> "MySQL seems to be running but is NOT accepting connections."

I tried to uninstall and reinstall MAMP at least 10 times. When I reinstall it, it starts working for about an hour, and then the same problem happens again.

I read many ways to fix the issue but none actually seem to work.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Here is what I have in MySQL Logs:

```
2020-05-21T05:48:25.6NZ mysqld_safe Logging to '/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error.log'.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.6NZ mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57
2020-05-21T05:48:25.773722Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --secure-file-priv: Current value does not restrict location of generated files. Consider setting it to a valid, non-empty path.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.773911Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.26) starting as process 8573 ...
2020-05-21T05:48:25.776884Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ is case insensitive
2020-05-21T05:48:25.778948Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2020-05-21T05:48:25.778971Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-05-21T05:48:25.778981Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
2020-05-21T05:48:25.778989Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-05-21T05:48:25.779008Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Adjusting innodb_buffer_pool_instances from 8 to 1 since innodb_buffer_pool_size is less than 1024 MiB
2020-05-21T05:48:25.779262Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-05-21T05:48:25.779376Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2020-05-21T05:48:25.780626Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2020-05-21T05:48:25.788888Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-05-21T05:48:25.803873Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.822650Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-05-21T05:48:25.822810Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-05-21T05:48:25.829388Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.830177Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.830203Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.830368Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-05-21T05:48:25.882963Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.26 started; log sequence number 611077514
2020-05-21T05:48:25.883431Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql57/ib_buffer_pool
2020-05-21T05:48:25.883557Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.889448Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.890010Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200520 22:48:25
2020-05-21T05:48:25.890635Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
2020-05-21T05:48:25.890661Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 8889
2020-05-21T05:48:25.890927Z 0 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
2020-05-21T05:48:25.891077Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.891547Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/Applications/MAMP/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.893468Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.893494Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.893505Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'root'@'::1' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.893514Z 0 [Warning] The plugin '0' used to authenticate user 'adaptivecrm'@'localhost' is not loaded. Nobody can currently login using this account.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.894944Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.894965Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.894974Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.894983Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.894991Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.896190Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.898286Z 0 [Note] Failed to start slave threads for channel ''
2020-05-21T05:48:25.907511Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.db is wrong. Expected 22, found 23. The table is probably corrupted
2020-05-21T05:48:25.907743Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
2020-05-21T05:48:25.908087Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column 'sql_mode' at position 14 to have type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','NOT_USED','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_ALL_TABLES','NO_ZERO_IN_DATE','NO_ZERO_DATE','INVALID_DATES','ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO','TRADITIONAL','NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER','HIGH_NOT_PRECEDENCE','NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION','PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH'), found type set('REAL_AS_FLOAT','PIPES_AS_CONCAT','ANSI_QUOTES','IGNORE_SPACE','IGNORE_BAD_TABLE_OPTIONS','ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY','NO_UNSIGNED_SUBTRACTION','NO_DIR_IN_CREATE','POSTGRESQL','ORACLE','MSSQL','DB2','MAXDB','NO_KEY_OPTIONS','NO_TABLE_OPTIONS','NO_FIELD_OPTIONS','MYSQL323','MYSQL40','ANSI','NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO','NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES','STRICT_TRANS_TABLES','STRICT_A
2020-05-21T05:48:25.908118Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
2020-05-21T05:48:25.908225Z 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.7.26'  socket: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 8889  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2020-05-21T05:48:26.012427Z 2 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
2020-05-21T05:48:26.023410Z 3 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
2020-05-21T05:48:26.034458Z 4 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
2020-05-21T05:48:26.044946Z 5 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
2020-05-21T05:48:26.054964Z 6 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
2020-05-21T05:48:30.802073Z 7 [Note] Plugin '0' is not loaded
```

Comment: It looks like you have mariadb table structures on a MySQL-5.7.26 server instance. This will not work. I suggest getting a mariadb to run on this data directory and it will have a better chance of working.

Comment: Ok thanks! but how do i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happened in fact was that I ran a SQL command that was generated by a system using MariaDB.
For this reason, since when I was loading MySQL on my machine, it was trying to fire up this specific database too that was formatted for MariaDB.

I had to wipe up MAMP totally in order to fix this problem.

Thanks @danblack for guiding me!